# How to insert a negative test case in the controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, .net-core, dependency-injection

I have a method `InsertTitle` that inserts a book in the database. Two of the test case in regards to this functionality are to verify how the system behaves when the ISBN entered is valid and when it is not valid.

A valid ISBN matches the following regEx pattern: `string pattern = "[0-9]*[-| ][0-9]*[-| ][0-9]*[-| ][0-9]*";`

The first issue I am having is figuring out in which class should the ISBN check happen to avoid dependencies. As you will see in the code snippets, I tried doing that in the **TitleController.cs** but without success in writing a proper, working code.

**TitleController.cs**

```
[Route("api/title")]
    [HttpPost()]
    public IActionResult InsertTitle([FromBody] GtlTitle gtlTitle)
    {
        string pattern = "[0-9]*[-| ][0-9]*[-| ][0-9]*[-| ][0-9]*";
        Match m = Regex.Match(gtlTitle.ISBN, pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        if (m.Success)
        {
            try
            {
                return Ok(_gtlTitleRepository.InsertTitle(gtlTitle));
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }
        }
        else
            // return ??? 

    }
```

The second and main issue occurs here. What should I return on the `else` branch so that, when an UI will be made and the controller will be called from a View, I will be able to return a message stating that the ISBN is not valid? I could not find any proper return for an `IActionResult`.

**MockGtlTitleRepository : IGtlTitle Repository**

```
public GtlTitle InsertTitle([FromBody] GtlTitle gtlTitle)
    {

        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(_connection))
        {
            connection.Open();
            connection.Query<GtlTitle>(@"INSERT INTO GTL_TITLE (ISBN, VolumeName, TitleDescription, PublicationDate, AuthorID, PublisherID, TempID) 
                                                        OUTPUT INSERTED.ISBN, INSERTED.VolumeName 
                                                        VALUES (@ISBN, @VolumeName, @TitleDescription, @PublicationDate, @AuthorID, @PublisherID, @TempID)",
                                                       new
                                                       {
                                                           gtlTitle.ISBN,
                                                           gtlTitle.VolumeName,
                                                           gtlTitle.TitleDescription,
                                                           gtlTitle.PublicationDate,
                                                           gtlTitle.AuthorID,
                                                           gtlTitle.PublisherID,
                                                           gtlTitle.TempID
                                                       }).First();
            return gtlTitle;
        }
    }
```

Therefore, what should the `InsertTitle` method return on the `else` branch? Also, should this logic go into the **MockGtlTitleRepository** instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very similar to the answer above with an improvement in the BadRequest retured. Also, adding an try/catch is a good idea when working with database or external dependencies. You could also add a logger and use it when handling exceptions.

```
[Route("api/title")]
[HttpPost()]
public IActionResult InsertTitle([FromBody] GtlTitle gtlTitle)
{
    string pattern = "[0-9]*[-| ][0-9]*[-| ][0-9]*[-| ][0-9]*";
    Match m = Regex.Match(gtlTitle?.ISBN, pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
    if (!m.Success)
      return BadRequest($"Could not match ISBN: {gtlTitle?.ISBN}")
    try
    {
       var title = _gtlTitleRepository.InsertTitle(gtlTitle)
        return Ok(title);
    }
    catch (Exception ex){
       _logger.Error("Unhandled error occured", ex);
       return StatusCode((int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, ex);
    }

}
```

Comment: You could also add the error to ModelState for the particular property and then return BadRequest(ModelState). This will return a standard format response. Another option is to add a `[Regex]` attribute on the ISBN property in the model to auto-validate it (though in case of non-API controllers you do need to manually check if model state is valid at start of action)

Answer (score 1):

Your code could look something like this. Try to avoid using the else keyword as it is almost never necessary and makes your code longer than it should be. Use early returns to achieve this. Checking for a match is fine in the controller, but could be moved to a service of some kind. In this case I wouldn't choose for this route since it's such a small check. I don't see why the repository call has any reason to fail, try to avoid wrapping code in unnecessary try/catch blocks.

```
[Route("api/title")]
[HttpPost()]
public IActionResult InsertTitle([FromBody] GtlTitle gtlTitle)
{
    string pattern = "[0-9]*[-| ][0-9]*[-| ][0-9]*[-| ][0-9]*";
    Match m = Regex.Match(gtlTitle.ISBN, pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
    if (!m.Success)
      return BadRequest("Could not match")
    var title = _gtlTitleRepository.InsertTitle(gtlTitle)
    return Ok(title);
}
```